# php in_array - needle is array, check if all elements in needle exist in haystack

Tags: php, arrays, compare

Im starting to get no ideias to solve this or probably its more simples than i expecpt.
Hope someone can help:

Im try to verify if

array A

```
arrA = Array
(
    [0] => hindu
    [1] => inglês
)
```

exists in array B

```
arrb = Array
(
    [0] => active
    [1] => awsome
    [2] => speaker
    [3] => creative
    [4] => team leader
    [5] => project manager
    [6] => chinese
    [7] => hindu
    [8] => spanish
    [9] => english
) 

If(in_array($arrA , $arrB)){
echo true;
}
```

Meaning if the 2 elements of array A exist in Array B then return TRUE. ( Both elements not just one).
And the size of Array A is not always the same ( can have 1 to many elements).

I tryed in_array and various recursive functions, but no luck...

Anyone?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Check out [array_intersect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use array_diff() -

```
$all_elements_exist = count(array_diff($a, $b)) == 0 ? true : false;
```

Comment: I guessbesides converting to lower string I also have to remove the ponctuation from all letter to be a clear match...